# HTML from Dreamweaver to Muse not working properly

Tags: html, dreamweaver, muse

I've created a scrollable frame with an image inside in Dreamweaver. When I preview in a browser, everything seems to be working.

I need to put this frame and image in my Adobe Muse site. I've pasted the code in with the "Insert HTML Object" feature. When I preview my Muse site, the scrollable frame works, but my image does not show up. It's replaced by a blue box with a white question mark inside it.

How can I make the image show up in my Muse site?

Here's my code, brackets are replaced with parenthesis:

```
(div style="border: 1px solid #aaa;background-colo r:#f9efef; width:920; height:375px; overflow:auto; color:#FFF;")(p)
  (img src="PersonalSite/Portfolio.jpg" alt="" width="4325" height="350" /)(/p)
(/div)
```

Comment: Why are brackets replaced with parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why is probably because you didn't put style tags around your code.

Try to put it up like that and see if it helps :-)

(div style="border: 1px solid #aaa;background-colo r:#f9efef; width:920; height:375px; overflow:auto; color:#FFF;")(p)
  (img src="PersonalSite/Portfolio.jpg" alt="" width="4325" height="350" /)(/p)
(/div)